# Origin of “run for it” idiom

Tags: etymology

According to dictionary.com:

> **run for it**, to hurry away or flee, especially to evade something:
>   *You had better run for it before anyone else arrives.*

Does this idiom have some reasonable origin? Why is it “for *it*”? What exactly is *“it”*?

Comment: *it* refers to the reason you are running, as in "run for *your life*" (when a bad guy is chasing you) or "run for *the money*" (to get something of value).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about etymology, which is defined as off-topic in the Help center.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, is it possible to move the question to english.se?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[Make a run/break for it](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/make-a-break-for)*** are idiomatic expressions which date back to the first part of the 19th century. *Run and break*  mean "escape" here:

***Make a run/break for:***

> - ***Run toward something.*** For example, As soon as it ended, they made a break for the door, or I'll have to make a run for the plane.
> - ***The noun break here means “escape,” and both terms may be put as make a break or run for it, meaning “to escape or get away quickly.”***
> - For example, With the guards asleep, he decided to make a break for it, or The rain's stopped; let's make a run for it. [c. 1840 ]

The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms

Usage Example:

> - 1915, Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, The Valley of Fear, ch. 3:
>
>   - "By Gar! it was as well that he made a break for it before the note reached us! I guess he won't show his face in this valley again.